# Cannot read data from SSL_read_ex with non-blocking socket

Tags: c++, openssl, nonblocking, libssl

I'm having trouble using SSL_read_ex with non-blocking sockets, especially I'm having trouble when requesting an invalid resource from Google: https://www.google.com/<something invalid here>.

What happens is that if I try to do a GET / to google there is no problem and I can get the relative page, but if I try to request an invalid resource everything stops working.

DETAILED EXPLANATION:

I'm writing a wrapper for libssl that will be used within the interpreter I'm developing. Right now I'm developing a library to allow HTTP requests using my own language. The HTTP library needs to use the SSL wrapper to access https sites.

The wrapper library uses non-blocking sockets for data exchange and my current implementation of SSL is based on the following scheme:

1. I call SSL_read_ex (if there is data return to user, otherwise...)
2. If SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ I check if there are data that must be sent by reading from "out_bio", if present I send them and listen again
3. I receive data on the socket, write it to "in_bio" and call SSL_read_ex again

The code I'm referring to is this: https://github.com/ArgonLang/arlib/blob/main/ssl/socket.cpp#L140

Now this scheme always works except when I request a non-existing page from google (why google? it's the only site I've found that causes this strange behavior but I believe there are others)

To rule out other problems I tried to check with wireshark that there were actually no further packets arriving on my socket (and thus rule out an "event loop" side problem).
I have tried to make requests through wget and I have compared the packets sent by my wrapper with those sent by wget and I have not noticed any difference, wget manages without any problem to receive a 404 response from google.
My wrapper instead gets stuck on SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ even though there are no more incoming packets.

**SOLUTION:**

Ok, after further analysis I finally managed to solve the problem, in particular I set the following flag: SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY and enabled SSL_set_read_ahead.

Comment: Sounds like Google is telling you to GFO and terminating the connection rudely, and your code doesn't handle the error condition robustly. I haven't looked at the code (Stackoverflow isn't, unfortunately, a code review site, we only answer ***specific*** programming question), but you should look over your error handling logic.

Comment: Thank you, I followed your advice and after further analysis I was able to correct the problem.